# Keeping UISearchController Results when moving back in a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisearchcontroller

I'm working with UISearchController and running into such a seemingly basic problem, I can't believe I'm unable to find any answers about this anywhere.

I have a Nav VC -> TableView w/Search Bar -> New VC on my Storyboard.

I want my UISearchController to work similarly to searching in the iOS Mail app or Twitter - where selecting a result pushes to the New VC in the Nav VC, and going Back on the Nav Bar returns me to the search results.

The problem is that when I go Back, my search results are already reset. And when I tap on a Result, it's showing it under the UISearchController hierarchy (I guess) instead of the main Nav VC.

What I want to do is tap on a search result, and Push from my TableView to the New VC. The Search Results are still there in the background, so when I pop Back, my search results are there and I can choose another without re-performing the search.

I've tried messing around with DefinesPresentationContext in my main VC with the Search function, and as far as I can tell it's not making any difference. Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest storing the results in a variable and then passing the variable between the view controllers, by making use of the `prepareForSegue` function, and an unwind segue when going backwards.